# Proof of undefinability of the "Most" quantifier in first-order logic

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I believe that the quantifier "Most $x$ have property $P$" is not first-order definable, that is, not definable using universal and existential quantifiers and equality. More precisely, if we restrict our attention to the class of finite $\{P\}$-structures, (where $P$ is a unary predicate symbol), there is no formula of first-order logic that holds precisely of those structures where the cardinality of the set $\{x | P(x)\}$ is strictly greater than its complement $\{x | \neg P(x)\}$. However, I want to see a proof of that statement. It is intuitively plausible to me, but I want a proof that there is no clever way to define that quantifier.

Comment: See e.g. S. Peters  & D. Westerståhl, 2006, Quantifiers in Language and Logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shall sketch out a proof on a line of an argument that I learnt from Fred Landman's *Structures for Semantics* (Kluwer Academic Publishers, 1991). Let us first construe the grammatical quantifier *most* in a mathematical setting.

Suppose we have two sets $A$ and $B$. We denote the elements of the set $A$ by $\alpha$s and the elements of $B$ by $\beta$s. By the sentence

$$\text{most $\alpha$s are $\beta$s}$$

we understand that there are more $\alpha$s that are $\beta$s than $\alpha$s that are not $\beta$s. In set-theoretical terms,

$$\lvert A\cap B\rvert >\lvert A\backslash B\rvert$$

where $\lvert\;\rvert$ denotes the cardinality of a set.

Assume that there is a first-order formula $\upsilon(A, B)$ expressing this relation:

$$\text{most $\alpha$s are $\beta$s}\iff\upsilon(A, B)$$

First, we take up the infinite case. Let the predicate $P(x)$ express that $x$ is $\beta$. Using $P(x)$, we can set down two sequences of first-order formulas:

$\phi_{1}\equiv\exists x_{1}P(x_{1});\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\psi_{1}\equiv\exists x_{1}P(x_{1})$

$\phi_{2}\equiv\exists x_{1}\exists x_{2}(P(x_{1})\wedge P(x_{2})\wedge x_{1}\neq x_{2});\qquad\psi_{2}\equiv\exists x_{1}\exists x_{2}(\neg P(x_{1})\wedge\neg P(x_{2})\wedge x_{1}\neq x_{2})$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\vdots\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\vdots$

Thus, we have formulas expressing for any $k$ that at least $k\,\alpha$s are $\beta$s (to use as a reference to $\lvert A\cap B\rvert$)

$$\phi_{k}\equiv\exists x_{1}\exists x_{2}\cdots\exists x_{k}(P(x_{1})\wedge P(x_{2})\cdots\wedge P(x_{k})\wedge x_{1}\neq x_{2}\cdots\neq x_{k})$$

and that at least $k\,\alpha$s are not $\beta$s (to use as a reference to $\lvert A\backslash B\rvert$)

$$\psi_{k}\equiv\exists x_{1}\exists x_{2}\cdots\exists x_{k}(\neg P(x_{1})\wedge\neg P(x_{2})\cdots\wedge\neg P(x_{k})\wedge x_{1}\neq x_{2}\cdots\neq x_{k})$$

We collect all these formulas into a set $\Gamma =\{\upsilon(A, B), \phi_{1}, \phi_{2},\ldots, \psi_{1}, \psi_{2},\ldots\}$. Notice that from the model-theoretic aspect, $\Gamma$ is a theory.

A finite subset $\Gamma_{0}$ of $\Gamma$ is composed of some $\phi$-formulas, some $\psi$-formulas, and possibly, $\upsilon(A, B)$. Thus, $\Gamma_{0}$ states, in effect, that at least $n$ $\alpha$s are $\beta$s (i.e., $\lvert A\cap B\rvert\geq n$) and at least $m$ $\alpha$s are not $\beta$ (i.e., $\lvert A\backslash B\rvert\geq m$). $\Gamma_{0}$ has a model if $n>m$.

By the compactness theorem, there is a model of the theory $\Gamma$ if and only if  every finite subset $\Gamma_{0}$ of it has a model. Since any model of $\Gamma$ must satisfy all of the $\phi$-formulas and the $\psi$-formulas, $\Gamma$ has infinite models only. We may observe that both $A\cap B$ and $A\backslash B$ must be infinite on those models.

By Löwenheim-Skolem theorem, since $\Gamma$ has a model, it has a countable model $\mathfrak{A}$. So, $\mathfrak{A}\vDash\upsilon(A, B)$. Since $\mathfrak{A}$ is countable, both $A\cap B$ and $A\backslash B$ are countable. As noted, $A\cap B$ and $A\backslash B$ are infinite on $\mathfrak{A}$. Therefore, $\lvert A\cap B\rvert = \lvert A\backslash B\rvert$. Hence, $\mathfrak{A}\not\vDash\text{most $\alpha$s are $\beta$s}$, whereas, *ex hypothesi*, $\mathfrak{A}\vDash\upsilon(A, B)$. Therefore, contrary to our assumption, $\upsilon(A, B)$ does not define $\text{most $\alpha$s are $\beta$s}$.

Next, let us consider the case of finite models; we inspect whether there is a first-order formula $\upsilon$ such that for all $\mathfrak{A}_{<\omega}$

$$\mathfrak{A}_{<\omega}\vDash\text{most $\alpha$s are $\beta$s}\iff\mathfrak{A}_{<\omega}\vDash\upsilon(A, B)$$

That is, when interpreted, whatever the cardinalities of the sets involved in $\mathfrak{A}_{<\omega}$ are, $\upsilon(A, B)$ must be true whenever $\text{most $\alpha$s are $\beta$s}$ is true.

Depending on its [complexity](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/recursive-functions/#AritAnalHier) (measured by the number of quantifiers in the equivalent formula in prefix form or by the maximal blocks of the same type, existential or universal, quantifiers), every first-order formula has a bounding number $N$ above which the truth-value of the formula remains invariant (true or false) irrespective of the cardinalities of the sets involved. Thus, any combination of $\phi$-formulas and $\psi$-formulas have such an $N$.

As for the sentence $\text{most $\alpha$s are $\beta$s}$, there is no bounding number $N$; its truth-value varies with $\lvert A\cap B\rvert$ and $\lvert A\backslash B\rvert$.

We can see this by setting $\lvert A\cap B\rvert$ to $n$ and $\lvert A\backslash B\rvert$ to $m$. If $n>m$, the sentence is true. If $\lvert A\backslash B\rvert$ to a $k$ such that $k>n$, the truth-value of the sentence alternates to false. If $\lvert A\cap B\rvert$ to an $l$ such that $l>k$, the truth-value alternates to true. Since $k, l, n, m$ are arbitrary numbers, whatever $N$ we assume, there is a counter-example to it. Hence, a formula $\upsilon$ formalising the sentence $\text{most $\alpha$s are $\beta$s}$ cannot be first-order. Consequently, the quantifier *most*, as we know it from the grammar of natural language, is not definable also on finite models.

Answer (score 2):

I think your claim follows from [this zero-one law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_model_theory#Zero-one_laws) for first-order sentences in finite models.

If $\sigma$ consists of a single unary predicate $P$, then the probability that a random $\sigma$-structure of cardinality $n$ satisfies "most $x$ have property P" approaches $\frac12$ as $n\to\infty$, so this sentence cannot be first-order.